Condition Formatting color for stacked in stacked columm chart in PowerBI?
I'm trying to have dynamic color for stacked in stacked colum chart based on legends in PowerBI.
For example: I have quantity for X-axis, Y-axis with two values:
Component1: Consumer, Corporate, and Home Office

Component2: Technology, Furniture, and Office Supplies

and legend with Sub-Category: Accesories, Appliances, Art, Blinders, Bookcases,...
My expectation is to have dynamic color for stacked based on the value of the legend
For instance, If the legend (sub-category) is "Accessories", the color for the stacked in the stacked column should be Red, "Appliances" should be Blue...

I couldn't create a measure or even apply condition formatting (fx) for this chart. Is it because I have so many dimensions and fields for this chart?

Try to create a mapping table for your sub-categories :
ColorMapping = 
DATATABLE (
    "Sub-Category", STRING,
    "Color", STRING,
    {
        {"Accessories", "#FF0000"}, // Red
        {"Appliances", "#0000FF"},  // Blue
        {"Art", "#FFFF00"},         // Yellow
        {"Binders", "#00FF00"},     // Green
        {"Bookcases", "#FFA500"}    // Orange
    }
)

Then ceate a relationship between your main table and the ColorMapping table using the Sub-Category and create a measure based on the color column :
SubCategoryColor = 
RELATED(ColorMapping[Color])

In the format pane in your visual try to use the measure in the color option under the bar section.

Hi, it would be my first idea to go with. But as the community told me that stacked column chart with the legend is not supported to deal with conditional formatting for color. :(

Can you provide some data so I can try to find a workaround I thought you were talking about the bars
